# Error in creating y.tab.c file

Tags: linux, bison

I am trying to run the following command in the terminal (Linux UBUNTU):
bison -yd HML.y
I need to generate y.tab.c file. But I got an error:

```
HML.y:141.7-14: %type redeclaration for model
HML.y:123.7-14: previous declaration
```

What does that error message mean? Could someone help me, please? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at line 123 and 141 in the **HML.y** file. See if the non-terminal **model** is declared on both lines, something like this:

```
%type <something> model;
```

Remove one of the two declarations.